# Selenium webdriver stops with no error-message when navigating through paypal login

Tags: python, selenium, paypal, webautomation

I'm trying to log into paypal.com and make a payment automatically.

The program successfully loads the login page(https://www.paypal.com/us/signin) and inputs the email, but when I click the next button the web driver unexpectedly closes without generating an error message.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Could it be because the next button is a disguised captcha, to keep robots from logging in?

I have already tried using time.sleep(3) to give the page time to load. I can't see any other issues with the code.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def paypal_pay(): # pass in user address

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    timeout = 20
    paypal = "https://www.paypal.com/us/signin"

    driver.get(paypal)
    email = "emailstuff@gmail.com"
    emailElement = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
    print(emailElement)
    emailElement.send_keys(email)
    time.sleep(3)
    nextElement = driver.find_element_by_id('btnNext').click()


def main():
    paypal_pay()
main()
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong to your code. Just add one more time.sleep(3)  below line nextElement =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine but the way that you have implemented is causing the problem, I mean you are using the `main()` method and what it will do is, once this method gets called and executed, it will close all the connections at end. Hence the reason your browser also getting closed without any error because your code is working fine till there:

Try the below modified code without main method which works completely fine :

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe");

paypal = "https://www.paypal.com/us/signin"

driver.get(paypal)
email = "hello@gmail.com"
emailElement = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
print(emailElement)
emailElement.send_keys(email)
time.sleep(3)
nextElement = driver.find_element_by_id('btnNext').click()

print("=> Done...")
```

For more info on `main()`, refer [this link](https://www.journaldev.com/17752/python-main-function)

I hope it helps...

Comment: Hi @Black_lotus, check my answer and let me know it is working or not? Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code After click on next button the Chrome browser crashes and in console i can see the following error.

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="577ff51b46a27eefeda43ccd320db48b", element="0.571535141628553-1")>
```

That means you need to start a `RemoteWebDriver` instead of `ChromeDriver`.

Step 1: Download the `Selenium Standalone Server` from following link

```
https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
```

Step 2: open command prompt as an administrator go to the downloaded path and type the below command and press enter

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
```

Step 3: To verify Hub is running, open a browser and type the below url.Default port of hub is `4444`

```
http://localhost:4444/grid/console
```

Step 4: Use the following code.If you follow above steps properly it should work perfectly the below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

def paypal_pay(): # pass in user address


    desired_caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    grid_url = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"
    driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=desired_caps, command_executor=grid_url)
    paypal = "https://www.paypal.com/us/signin"
    driver.get(paypal)
    email = "emailstuff@gmail.com"
    emailElement = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
    print(emailElement)
    emailElement.send_keys(email)
    nextElement = driver.find_element_by_id('btnNext')
    nextElement.click()


def main():
    paypal_pay()
main()
```

Please let me know if this work for you.Good Luck.

Comment: `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="577ff51b46a27eefeda43ccd320db48b", element="0.571535141628553-1")>` is not crashing error, the OP is printing email id to the console.

Comment: Ok. I have just run his code and not working so I have provided an alternate options.